# Create filtered Subject to Observable in Angular

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, behaviorsubject

Hi I have a private `Subject` that I do not want to expose, so I am creating different `Observable`s from the single `Subject`:

```
public numberChange$: Observable<number>;
public oddChange$: Observable<number>;
public evenChange$: Observable<number>;
private number: Subject<number>;
constructor() {
  this.number = new Subject<number>();
  this.numberChange$ = this.number.asObservable();
  this.oddChange$ = this.number.filter(n => n % 2 === 1).asObservable();
  this.evenChange$ = this.number.filter(n => n % 2 === 0).asObservable();
}
```

So that others can subscribe to `numberChange$` if they want to know when the number has changed. If they want to know ONLY when the change is an odd number, they can subscribe to `oddChange$`. Same goes for `evenChange$`.

The code above does not work because after `this.number.filter()` I cannot call `asObservable()` anymore. How do you fix the code above to achieve what I have described?

Comment: The filter operator returns an Observable, you do not need to call asObservable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `Observable` is returned from `Observable.filter`. So there isn't a need to call `asObservable()`, just subscribe to the returned value.

```
this.number = new Subject<number>();
this.numberChange$ = this.number.asObservable();
this.oddChange$ = this.number.filter(n => n % 2 === 1);
this.evenChange$ = this.number.filter(n => n % 2 === 0);
this.oddChange$.subscribe((x) => { console.log(x) } );
```